# If Menber Active than fill name else check other in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

Active Member

name of member in active member column only if Active is "A" Else check other row in Name column 
also no column should be empty
Please help

[image: Active Member Only]

Comment: Your description of very fuzzy, please describe exactly the rules you need to follow. Some screenshot with desired output may help.

Answer (score 0):

Select Name and apply Filter (Sort & Filter, Filter on Home Tab), filter Active column = A you will have all the Active name, then select, copy and paste under Active Member you will have your list then remove the filter.                 To know how to apply Filter follow the link http://www.excel-easy.com/data-analysis/filter.html