# Name in output column should be present only active member is "A" Else should check next row also now cell should be empty or Zero

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

[image: Active member display]

I Have two workbook one have data as shown in image Sheet 1
and second workbook is output sheet2
The problem is I want data in  output sheet from sheet 1 only if active column in sheet 1 Have " A" also the cell in output sheet should not be empty or 0 
As shown in image Sheet 2

Pls help

Comment: Why are you asking the same question again? Please don't do that, read and take note of [What should I do if no one answers my question?](http://superuser.com/help/no-one-answers) instead of asking the same question again. If you have new information you should edit it into the original question instead of asking a new one.

Comment: You already asked [If Menber Active than fill name else check other in excel](http://superuser.com/q/1053489), where you have been given an answer. If that answer doesn't work for you then leave a comment on explaining why.

Comment: ok will not repeat

Answer (score 0):

In *Sheet1* cell **C2** enter:

```
=IF(B2="A",1+MAX($C$1:C1),"")
```

and copy down.  This yields:

[image]

Then in *Sheet2* cell **A2** enter:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!A:A,MATCH(ROWS($1:1),Sheet1!C:C,0))
```

This yields:

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

To get rid of that annoying error message, in *Sheet2*, cell **A2** use this formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!A:A,MATCH(ROWS($1:1),Sheet1!C:C,0)),"")
```

If you copy this down, it will hide the errors at the bottom of the column.

Comment: Solution solved the problem .But when the formula is drag in sheet 2 it shows #N/A for cell A5 and futher

Comment: @AjayBadgujar  It should................do you want the error to vanish ??

Comment: yes that error should vanish or show empty cell

Comment: please help for the error

Comment: @AjayBadgujar  Please see my **EDIT#1:**